# Classic 3 tier / n-tier architecture with RIA Services, Silverlight and Prism

Tags: c#, silverlight

I currently am attempting to architect a solution based on existing technology.

I currently have a 3-tier solution (Model[Entity Framework], Model Access, Business Logic) which I would like to extend. However I do not wish to modify the existing business objects as they are currently quite beneficial and in use. However I'm looking for a good reference as to patterns and practices as to implementing my business logic across to a Domain Service / RIA service for use with my Prism based Silverlight application. I'm curious as to how the domain objects come into play in the classic pattern and I do not wish to invalidate my current and classic pattern based on this new technology. Does anyone have a good reference to classic n-tier or 3-tier solutions with RIA services ? An allround reference involving usage and coverage of the classic pattern with these latest additions it would be much appreciated. I do not wish to directly reference my models from my web application and if possible have even my domain logic seperated. Currently I have roughly created the following:

My backing Modules

- [Module]

  - Model
  - Service
- [Module].[Access]

  - ModelAccess
- [Module].[Business]

  - ModelLogic
- [Module].[Presentation] (New)

  - ViewModels
  - Views
- [Shell]
- [Web]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look into the documentation on [Prism](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd943055.aspx).  Prism contains the modularity framework you need to create self-contained "plugins" for a Silverlight application.